# Debugging CodeIgniters 404 errors

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I'm having a nightmare uploading my site to the production server. The site runs fine locally and on a staging server (exactly the same server, settings as the production site). However when I deploy to production I'm getting a 404 error from CI.

CodeIgniters 404 error pages are frustrating because it seems as if i can't access other libraries from them. How can I go about debugging the error? See which controller is trying to be called etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I would check for more info are the logs located under CIroot -> system -> logs.

Also changing the logging details might help. Locate :

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 1;
```

In your CIroot -> system -> application -> config -> config.php and change it to 4.